# Fixed Round-Robin scheduling with two processes and a quantum of 1

Tags: scheduling, round-robin

Morning,

I'm using fixed RR algorithm with a quantum of 1. P1 arrives at 0 and P5 arrives at 1. P1 has a burst time of 10 and P5 has a burst time of 5.

P1 executes from 0 to 1. P5 arrives at 1, but it goes to the back of the queue. Since there are only two processes at the start of 1, I believe P1 would execute from 1 to 2, P5 would wait one tick and first execute from 2 to 3.

Is this correct? If not, would P5 execute immediately from 1 to 2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct,the OS prefers a recently ended process to a newly entered one when `end time of p1=start time of p5`
the following question may be useful
[Special case scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360925/special-case-scheduling?rq=1)